# Making two dictionaries from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a_o','a','b_o','b','c'],'B':[1,0,1,1,0],'C':[99,24,67,89,91]})
```

For the above dataframe df, I want to make two dictionary as below:

```
 dict1 = {'a_o':99,'b_o':67}
 dict2 = {'a':0,'b':1,''c':0}
```

What I want to do is, for all entries ending with '_o' in column 'A', I want to make a dictionary dict1 and map its keys to corresponding value of column 'C'. For all other entries in column 'A', I want to make a dictionary dict2 and map its keys to corresponding value of column 'B'.

How can I do that?
I was trying to make two dataframes,one for those rows whose entries in column 'A' ends with '_o', other dataframe for the rest rows. If I achieve this I'll be able to make dict1 and dict2 using `dict(zip(____))`. But I couldn't make dataframes. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
m = df.A.str.endswith("_o")
dict1 = dict(zip(df.loc[m, "A"], df.loc[m, "C"]))
dict2 = dict(zip(df.loc[~m, "A"], df.loc[~m, "B"]))

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

Prints:

```py
{'a_o': 99, 'b_o': 67}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
```